# How to get sum of numbers in one cell google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, office365, spreadsheet

I need to sum up all values in one cell and get the total result. Note that there is also text in parenthesis as well. Here in the picture I need to know the Total for "Lenovo[image]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
=SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B2, "[^\d\.]+", "|"), "|"))
```

[image]

Comment: yes the solution is good, just want to know if there is another way to do this, because here if there is a number inside the parenthesis, then it is also considered as a  number and sums up

Comment: If you mean something like: 100 (3 adapters) + 200 (2 cases) + 50 (5 batteries), then you can just add `(` to your formula: `=SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B2, "[^\d\.(]+", "|"), "|"))`

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't work, since if I have something like: 100 (3 adapters for T450 model) + 200 (2 cases for T460 model) + 50 (5 batteries for Carbon X1), then the  numbers inside their model names are also being calculated